# choosing firewall: ufw vs nftables vs iptables

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firewall

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 on embedded system and I need to choose a firewall app between the followings: ufw, nftables, iptables.

Can you recommend one of them and why its better than the others?

Thanks

Comment: please note: `ufw` uses `iptables` *under the hood*, and, in a system that has `nftables`, the `iptables` is basically using `nftables` through `xtables-nft` shim ... so ... in summary ... use `ufw`

Comment: If you want to use Docker or any other container runtime, it's probably better to use iptables. Most interfere with nftables. I think lxc works with nftables. But definitely check nftables compatibility before implementing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are essentially two separate firewall stacks in the kernel: the older iptables-based stack, and the newer nftables-based stack.  However, because some programs are designed to work with one and some with the other, and mixing and matching tends to cause lots of hard-to-troubleshoot breakage, on most modern systems, the iptables binary actually interacts with the nftables-based stack, so either one can be used.

ufw is designed to make firewall configuration easy.  If you want to just have an easy-to-configure firewall, it's a great choice.  If you need more complicated configuration, then nftables is a good choice for that because you can create a single file that has all the rules and then atomically update the rules, and it's a lot easier to work with than the iptables binary.  If you're unsure, ufw is probably the right choice.